# Rows to column transformation in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables

- DimInstitution (InstitutionKey, name)
- BridgeInstitutionRole (InstitutionKey, InstitutionRoleKey)
- DimInstitutionRole (InstitutionRoleKey, InstitutionRoleCode)

But, one `InstitutionKey` can have many `InstitutionRoleCode`. Please see the example

[image]

Now, `InstitutionRole` can have new values as well. I want to create the dynamic `InstitutionRoleCode` columns based on its value.

My expected output will be:

[image]

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Rows to columns using 'Pivot' in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15931607/convert-rows-to-columns-using-pivot-in-sql-server)

Comment: you need to do more digging, go to http://sqlfiddle.com/  and muck up some data